# Generate images for html heading with Java servlet

Tags: java, html

I found [Facelift](http://facelift.mawhorter.net) which can basically generate html headings as images (with "nice font") on the fly. Does something similar exist for Java (couldn't find one myself)?

Cheers,
stephanos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have look at http://swit.kornr.net/ Its for Wicket, but perhaps it can be used without it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any, but you should probably consider a more accessible alternative (non-image) like CSS 3 embedded fonts, which allow any fonts (even TTF, OTF and other common font formats) to be used in the page, while behaving like proper text.

My website, http://azabani.com/ uses CSS3 embedded fonts, so check that out as an example.

Comment: I'd recommend against it, as there are numerous accessibility and usability issues which are quite annoying, which are not present in native CSS 3 fonts (but exist in Flash-based solutions like cufon)

Comment: actually to my knowledge cufón uses javascript which then uses native browser capabilities (e.g. canvas) to display the fonts - but you're essentially right, CSS 3 would be a much better approach once the currently existing minor problems are fixed

Answer (score 0):

yes, I created a image generator, which could be tweaked to generate any sort of image you want.

If you host this on Azure "function apps" , it costs only **pennies per month**.

https://github.com/djangofan/chord-bars